# Как расширить фон шапки таблицы за ее пределы?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на **wordpress** и в нем таблица - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/vstufp9n/). Как сделать так, чтобы фон заголовка `thead` распространялся на всю ширину страницы так, и при этом, чтобы ячейки сохранили свое местоположение? Может быть есть способ выносить заголовок за пределы таблицы, как это можно делать с инпутами формы? В любом случае, не хотелось бы двигать `<div class="col-full">` т.к. `wordpress` напичкан вставками различных функций.

```css
.col-full {
  width: 980px;
  margin-right:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
thead {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-full">
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="product-thumbnail">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Корзина</h1>
      </th>
      <th class="product-name">Обработка заказов производится<br>с 09:00 до 18:00</th>
      <th class="product-subtotal">Итого</th>
      <th class="product-remove"><button>Оформить заказ</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        thumbnail
      </td>
      <td class="product-name" data-title="Товар">
        Товар
      </td>
      <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Итого">
        Итого
      </td>
      <td class="product-remove">
        Удалить эту позицию</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: ну а почему col-full не обернуть div с шириной 100% и желтым бэкграундом?

Comment: @KAGG Design потому что бекграунд нужен в рамках высоты `thead` как полоса на белом фоне по сути или я вас не понял?

Answer (score 1):

Надо натянуть абсолютный блок на thead, с помощью псевдоэлемента after.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-full {
  width: 980px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

thead {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

thead:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-full">
  <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="product-thumbnail">
          <h1 class="entry-title">Корзина</h1>
        </th>
        <th class="product-name">Обработка заказов производится<br>с 09:00 до 18:00</th>
        <th class="product-subtotal">Итого</th>
        <th class="product-remove"><button>Оформить заказ</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
        <td class="product-thumbnail">
          thumbnail
        </td>
        <td class="product-name" data-title="Товар">
          Товар
        </td>
        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Итого">
          Итого
        </td>
        <td class="product-remove">
          Удалить эту позицию</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: но, в таком случае все сразу окрашивается в желтый, а это не то, что мне нужно, чтобы была желтая полоса по высоте в рамках `thead` и на всю ширину

Comment: тогда надо натягивать абсолютный блок. Поправил ответ.

Comment: не совсем. у вас почему-то ячейки таблицы (товар,итого) выпали за саму таблицу

Comment: У вас как в вопросе? Только thead покрашен. Я так и сделал.

Comment: посмотрите внимательно - вы присвоили `thead`  `display: block;` и ячейки выпали за пределы таблицы

Comment: Я вам дал идею кода: использовать абсолютный блок. Примерно набросал, как  это должно выглядеть. Допиливать код - ваша задача.

Comment: спасибо, уже. решение ниже

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col-full {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
thead {
  background-color:yellow;
  height: 85px;
}
thead::before {
  content: '';
  left: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500%;
  height: 85px;
  display: block;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-full">
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="product-thumbnail">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Корзина</h1>
      </th>
      <th class="product-name">Обработка заказов производится<br>с 09:00 до 18:00</th>
      <th class="product-subtotal">Итого</th>
      <th class="product-remove"><button>Оформить заказ</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        thumbnail
      </td>
      <td class="product-name" data-title="Товар">
        Товар
      </td>
      <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Итого">
        Итого
      </td>
      <td class="product-remove">
        Удалить эту позицию</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

но это не лучшее решение

Comment: Добавьте описание или комментарии к коду, чтобы автор не просто использовал ваше решение, а понял ваш ход мыслей.

Comment: @Денис Ткачук это вообще не решение

Answer (score 0):

@KAGG Design доработал ваше решение с абсолютным блоком - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/6yugq67a/)

```css
.col-full {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 980px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 82px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

thead {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="col-full">
  <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="product-thumbnail">
          <h1 class="entry-title">Корзина</h1>
        </th>
        <th class="product-name">Обработка заказов производится<br>с 09:00 до 18:00</th>
        <th class="product-subtotal">Итого</th>
        <th class="product-remove"><button>Оформить заказ</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
        <td class="product-thumbnail">
          thumbnail
        </td>
        <td class="product-name" data-title="Товар">
          Товар
        </td>
        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Итого">
          Итого
        </td>
        <td class="product-remove">
          Удалить эту позицию</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```